# how to disable button2 if button1 is clicked and disable button2 if button1 is clicked.

Tags: jquery

I have code setup like so:

```
<form>
    <button id="button1">button1</button>
    <button id="button2">button2</button>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Initially how would I make my submit button disabled until either button1 or button2 is clicked?

The most important question is how to enable the disabled button while at the same time disabling the alternate button. This is so that the user can only submit one of the button's values and not both buttons.

I'm aware that I would use `$('#button').attr("disabled", "disabled")` to add the disabled attribute and also set the button by using `$('#button').attr("disabled", true)` or `$('#button').attr("disabled", false)`. I'm also aware that `.removeAttr` method removes attributes however im unsure how to piece this all together. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: when to enable the button?

Comment: But how can to click button2 when its disabled on click of button1.

Comment: Ideally you should use radio inputs, as that's what they're for.  Also, this isn't what buttons are for and people expect common behavior for common controls.

Comment: @Archer Could I hide the radio button so that my button design acts as a radio button if you get what I mean?

Comment: You could style the radio buttons to look however you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Assuming you need this.*

```js
$(function() {
    $("#button1, #button2").click(function(event){
      //Since <button> elements are submit buttons by default.
      event.preventDefault(); 
      
      //Enable other button
      $("#button1, #button2").not(this).prop('disabled', false);
      
      //Disable the current
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      
      //Enable submit
      $('#btnsubmit').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <button id="button1">button1</button>
    <button id="button2">button2</button>
    <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: Dont forget, he also wants the submit button initally disabled and then enabled after one of the two other buttons is clicked

Comment: Thanks @AmmarCSE or can you enable both buttons and not disable button2 and the submit button initially?

Comment: @Billy, Does this fulfills your requirement? If you don't want any button `disabled` remove the attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this one i have made out a fiddle. I have Made out both types of fiddles refer it

[Fiddle for the button action](https://jsfiddle.net/xq9rxs97/1/)

[Fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/xq9rxs97/4/)
Used code Snippet

```
    $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled","disabled");
$("button").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("button").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
            $(this).siblings().removeAttr("disabled");
            $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
            return false;
        });        
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but with this code the button I click gets disabled

Comment: I have made another one take

Comment: @SaiDeepak, You should go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr and also you don't need each when binding event

Comment: @SaiDeepak no you've done the opposite of what I want. I wanted the alternative button disabled not the one I click

Comment: Check it out i have provided 2 fiddles just check both of them

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it also tells you which is disabled,

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button1, #button2").click(function() {
    $("#button1, #button2").not(this).prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  });

  $("form").on("submit", function() {
    alert("disabled button:" + $("input:disabled").attr("id"));


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <input type="button" id="button1" disabled value="button1" />

  <input type="button" id="button2" value="button2" />

  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```